# Controls menu in Unity - choose buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-input

I am trying to add a menu in my 2D unity game where the user can specify which controls they prefer to use in the game. Right now I have a script where the code for the main character movements are specified as follows:

```
private void Update()
{
    // Set the new direction based on the current input
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        movement.SetDirection(Vector2.up);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        movement.SetDirection(Vector2.down);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        movement.SetDirection(Vector2.left);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        movement.SetDirection(Vector2.right);
    }

    // Rotate the main character to face the movement direction
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(movement.direction.y, movement.direction.x);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle * Mathf.Rad2Deg, Vector3.forward);
}
```

Instead of for example `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)` I'd like to listen to what the user has typed in, in a "controls" menu. However, I don't know how this menu should be connected to the script.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be done or if there is some website/video that I can watch where this is implemented?

Thanks in advance,

N

Answer (score 0):

Ah, key binding. There is no *easy* way of adding keybinds.

You would have to loop through all the keycodes and see if any are pressed. It isn't efficient but it works in this context.

```
foreach(KeyCode kcode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
{
    if (Input.GetKey(kcode))
    {
        // Set key to given keycode.
        return;
    }
}
```

After that, you should save what key the user pressed into a file or into `PlayerPrefs`.

When the player starts the game again, just read it and set it back.